# Typedef C Struct: invalid use of incomplete typedef

Tags: c, gcc, struct, typedef

I'm getting the following errors while trying to typedef a struct. I've done this before and am following the exact same format as I have before but something isn't working and I'm completely stumped.

Shm_channel.h:

```
typedef struct _msgQ_info msgQ_info;
/*
 * This function initializes and returns a mesQ_info struct for
 * the user 
 */
 msgQ_info init_message_queue();
```

Shm_channel.c:

```
// Struct that contains all the message queue information
struct _msgQ_info {
    mqd_t descriptor;
    mode_t mode;
    char *name;
};
```

Other_file.c:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <mqueue.h>

#include "shm_channel.h"

//... Inside of Main()
    msgQ_info msgQinfo;
      msgQinfo = init_message_queue();
      if(0 > open_message_queue(&msgQinfo)){
        fprintf(stderr, "message queue descriptor failed to be initialized in webproxy.c\n");
        return 0;
      }else{
        fprintf(stderr, "Message queue descriptor successfully created with value : %d\n", msgQinfo.descriptor);
      }
```

Errors:

[image]

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Comment: How is the compiler for `Other_file.c` supposed to know how larger the structure is? And which layout it has?

Comment: You can't declare variables of a structure type without the complete structure definition being given first.  Otherwise the compiler has no idea how much memory to allocate for it.  So move the structure definition out of that `.c` file and into the `.h` file.

Comment: Thanks @TomKarzes, adding the structure definition in the .h file worked. I wanted to keep the definition of the structure private. Is there a way to do that and keep the definition in the .c file? That's what I thought I did before.

Comment: @EvanStenger: You can use and pass around a pointer to a struct without having to know its definition. You won't be able to directly access any of its members, though, you'll have to work through an interface of functions.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: Ok that sounds familiar. I'm pretty sure that's what I did before. Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add

```
#include "shm_channel.c"
```

before

```
#include "shm_channel.h"
```

in Other_file.c

Your compiler considered `msgQ_info` as a "incomplete typedef", because you didn't tell it what `struct _msgQ_info` is. Since the declaration of `struct _msgQ_info` has already existed in `shm_channel.c`, you just need to `#include` it.

---

Alternatively, add the declaration to `shm_channel.h`.

```
// Struct that contains all the message queue information
struct _msgQ_info {
    mqd_t descriptor;
    mode_t mode;
    char *name;
};

typedef struct _msgQ_info msgQ_info;
/*
 * This function initializes and returns a mesQ_info struct for
 * the user 
 */
msgQ_info init_message_queue();
```

---

I personally prefer the second approach, for it makes your project more clear.

Answer (score 4):

**Is `msgQ_info` intended to be an opaque type?** If so, you shouldn't be tampering with it from outside of Shm_channel.c.

Consider the reasons for such a design... Do you think it's possible that the author was trying to prevent non-portable internals from leaking past the abstraction and into what's supposed to be portable code?

Should you decide to tamper with it, you should probably be doing so within the confines of Shm_channel.c, where the structures (non-portable?) internals are isolated to.

Answer (score -2):

In Other_file.c replace "shm_channel.h" with "shm_channel.c"

And at the beginning of **shm_channel.c** have:

```
#include "shm_channel.h"
```

Any .h file should be included in the .c file with the same (unqualified) name.